# Is there any biological basis for the emphasis on the value of the firstborn son?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, epigenetics

Is the firstborn son biologically different in any way from the sons that follow?

Perhaps his epigenome is different? I have heard that a man's testosterone levels decrease when he becomes a father -- could this then have implications for the epigenetics of subsequent sons?

Comment: King Joeffrey was a monster. His younger brother, King Tommen, was a sweetie. Jamie is a heartthrob. Tywin somewhat less so (as a dwarf.) So yes, of course sons are different, but not in any predictable way. (Sorry to use fiction to answer, but it's as accurate as anything else on this matter.)

Comment: This report from 1 million babies finds a negative effect on health at birth for lower parity offspring: https://cinch.uni-due.de/fileadmin/content/research/workingpaper/1513_CINCH-Series_ardilamolitor.pdf. Whether that is due to biological characteristics of the babies themselves or the mother is not clear.

Comment: The firstborn son has equal chances of birth asphyixiation, being born blue, and having negative traits like autism, as the other children, based on the egg-sperm combination. The quality of the gametes of a traditional female mother from age 16 to 30 let's say, does not vary that much.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of cases reported now that suggest that overall the firstborn child is usually more intelligent. The [articles supporting this](http://jhr.uwpress.org/content/early/2016/11/01/jhr.53.1.0816-8177.abstract) are based on behavioural and economic study though, so the biological basis is a little lacking.

It's also not clear if this is nature or nurture. The firstborn may benefit from their parents undivided attention disproportionately.

Here's the [press release](http://www.ed.ac.uk/news/2017/first-borns-have-mental-edge-study-shows) for it. And the coverage from the [Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/first-born-child-more-intelligent-smarter-siblings-younger-eldest-sibling-university-of-edinburgh-a7570606.html)
and [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/brucelee/2017/02/12/study-says-the-oldest-child-is-the-smartest/#4ab539e24d9c)

I read somewhere that the firstborn is more likely to be overweight too, but I can't find the article now. Other people may know other traits that are supposed to differ between children.

Comment: There are apparently downvotes on this. I realise there are non-scientific links but I only provided them for completion. If anyone has a problem with the answer they should provide a constructuve comment with their vote.

Comment: It would be more representative of the literature to also report the magnitude of the detected IQ effect, which was roughly 1.5 units in this larger study: http://www.pnas.org/content/112/46/14224.

Comment: I expect that 1.5 units probably derives from the cultural effect of competition and favouritism, and the higher likelihood of the the other children to have depression.

Answer (score -3):

I remember reading/hearing something about the effect of older brothers on the chances of people becoming certain types of people.

It went something like the oldest was most likely to be a pilot/doctor/CEO etc.

The second was most likely to be a teacher/middle management etc.

There's plenty of blogs that suggest the more older brothers a man has, the more likely they are to be [homosexual](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21929330.700-chance-inheritance-the-subtle-power-of-birth-order/?full=true#.VHSNAGSOQ6R). But this obviously doesn't look at whether or not Biological influences lead to this "birth order effect", or cultural influences.

I remember a suggestion that it was to do with antibodies (or some other substance) that builds up in the mother's womb after having son's. But again I can't find any evidence for that, so it might be pure speculation.

NB. I don't subscribe to this theory, but if you're really interested, it might be worth looking at the science behind it.